# Rearrange $y = xa-zc$ so that $a-c$ is on one side of the equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to rearrange the following equation so that $a - c$ is on one side of the equation?
$$
y = xa-zc
$$
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Not if you want $a-c$ to be the *only* appearances of $a$ and $c$ in the rewritten equation.

Otherwise, it's easy, of course:
$$ y-xa+zc+a-c = a-c $$

You can achieve that *one* of $a$ and $c$ appear only as part of $a-c$, at the cost of assuming that $x$ or $z$ is nonzero:

$$ \frac{y - (x-z)c}{x} = a-c $$

Answer (score 0):

$y + za = xa -zc + za \iff y + za = z(a-c) + xa \iff \dfrac{y+za-xa}{z} = a-c$